# How to exclude HTML elements by ID or class using HTTrack or bash script

Tags: bash, html, script

I need to copy a website, but I want to exclude specific HTML elements by ID or class in all pages (using a bash script).

I need this because I don't want ads or some other annoying features of some websites.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but it was too big for the comment box and I hope it puts you on the right track.

Stripping those things out while HTTrack is processing the files might be hard. They have a C API for plug-ins that seems to provide hooks you could use to strip out chunks of the document before HTTrack scans it for further URLs to download, but I don't see a scripting interface for that (someone else might have written one, though).

Stripping those things out *after* HTTrack has downloaded the files would be easier, but bash probably isn't the best choice here, because you'd have to spend a lot of time teaching bash how to parse HTML. You'd probably do better to use a more advanced scripting language that has good HTML/DOM libraries built-in or freely available (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.).